# How to add a colored filter effect on an image?

Tags: image, eclipse-rcp, filtering

I am building an Eclipse RCP application, based on eclipse 3.5.

I'd like to modify an image at runtime. The image is loaded and will be used as an icon, but depending on the situation, I'd like to add a filter on the image to give it a red or orange color, depending on some user-configured value.

It's the image transformation that I'm interested in. I already know how to get the image and ask a component to display it.

Has anybody done that? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are possibly many choices for doing just that, you can use ImageIO to load an image as BufferedImage and then get the Graphics2D and modify it as you wish. When you are finished modifying you can reaasign the newly created image back into your component which holds the original image and thats it.
You can of course look for some libraries to allow you easier image manipulation, maybe jmagick or something similar.

Comment: Not that easy it seems... I have a org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image
and cannot get it's Graphics instance because ImageIO's read(InputStream) method returns null.

Comment: I didn't really use your answer as is, but it sent me in the right direction, thank you! I finally used a new GC to modify the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DecoratingLabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/DecoratingLabelProvider.html) with a suitable [`ILabelDecorator`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ILabelDecorator.html). See also [FAQ What is a label decorator?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_label_decorator?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alexey! What I've not been able to do up to now is modifying the image, not replacing it in its context. Maybe my question was not clear on that point, I'm going to update it.